# How to fix NextAuth redirects to 404 error issue?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make NextAuth work but it isn't calling the [..nextAuth].js file. It redirects the user onClick of Login button to:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Flogin
```

[image]

If you notice my code below I have used redirect: false prop and passing the CredentialProvider.

Upon consoling on my [..NextAuth].js file I don't receive anything.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong that even after putting redirect to false it's still redirecting and why nextAuth file is not able to receive anything from Login?

Here's my login file:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";
import styles from "../../styles/login.module.css";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as AuthAct from "../../redux/actions/AuthAct";
import { Container, Button, InputAdornment, IconButton, CircularProgress } from 
"@material-ui/core";
import { Visibility, VisibilityOff } from '@mui/icons-material';
import InputField from "../../components/controls/input";
import constants from "../../constants/constants.json";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

const Login = ({ req_login }) => {
// Localization
const { t } = useTranslation('login');

const router = useRouter();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

// Cat eye
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
});

const [loader, setLoader] = React.useState(false)
const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false);
const handleClickShowPassword = () => setShowPassword(show => !show);
const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
};

const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

const onLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false
    })
};

return (
    <>
        {/* START OF HEAD */}
        <Head>
            <title>
                {t("login:seo_title", {
                    platform_name_en: `${constants.platform_name_en}`,
                    platform_name_ur: `${constants.platform_name_ur}`,
                })}
            </title>
            <meta
                name="description"
                content="You can create new password by using the form"
            />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>{/* END OF HEAD */}
        {/* START OF CONTAINER */}
        <Container>
            <Row className={styles["login-container"]}>
                <Col lg={4} className="m-auto">
                    <h5 className="mb-3">{t("title")}</h5>
                    <p>{t("desc")}</p>
                    <InputField
                        label={t("label_email")}
                        type="email"
                        placeholder={t("placeholder_email")}
                        onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                        value={values.email}
                        className="mb-3"
                        name="email"
                    />
                    <InputField
                        label={t("label_pwd")}
                        type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                        placeholder={t("placeholder_pwd")}
                        onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                        value={values.password}
                        className="mb-3"
                        name="password"
                        endadornment={
                            <InputAdornment>
                                <IconButton
                                    aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                                    onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                                >
                                    {showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                                </IconButton>
                            </InputAdornment>
                        }
                    />
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className="mui-btn-block"
                        onClick={onLogin}
                        disabled={loader}
                    >
                        {loader ?
                            <CircularProgress
                                size={20}
                                thickness={5}
                            /> : t("login")}
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    </>
);
};

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
const token = req?.cookies?.accessToken;
// redirect to Landing page when error occur in server side rendering
if (token !== null && token !== "" && token !== undefined) {
    res.setHeader("location", "/dashboard");
    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.end();
}
// return data to main Page Props
return {
    props: {},
};
}

export default connect(null, AuthAct)(Login);
```

My [..nextAuth].js file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const authOptions = {
session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
},
providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
        type: "credentials",
        credentials: {},
        authorize(credentials, req) {

            alert("Coming here")
            const { email, password } = credentials;

            if (email !== "john@gmail.com" || password !== "1234") {
                return null;
            }

            return { email: "john@gmail.com", id: "1234", name: "John Doe", message: "Successfully Logged In" }
        }
    })
],
pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login"
}
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Comment: 0

I am having the same error.

Btw, @Robinhood, you should probably change to this export if you are using the APP router: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization